# Вывод списка ul в 2 столбика по 7 элементов

Tags: html, css, php

Добрый день. Прошу вашей помощи. Есть список:

```
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">пункт меню</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Он, естественно, выводит все пункты списка друг под другом. 
Необходимо вывести эти пункты меню в 2 столбика по 7 пунктов в каждом, как на сайте cheaptool.ru в подменю. 
Там при наведении на меню открывается подменюшка большая и там пункты меню в 2 столбика.

Скажите, каким образом это возможно сделать средствами html и css? И возможно ли? 
Также интересует реализация и через php, опять же, если возможно...

Очень буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b1pqpgya/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сыром виде как-то так:

```
ul {
    width: 100%; // или 400px
}

ul > li {
    width: 50%; // или 200px
    float: left;
}
```